# Instagram Location Data

Tags: location, instagram, instagram-api

I am working on developing a platform which is integrated with Instagram. My app is still in the review process currently but would like some clarification on what is the best way to build one of the modules.

An important part of our application involves us selecting the most appropriate user to carry out a task. In order to make this decision, we need to see the demographic information of a certain user’s followers. More precisely, we need to know how many followers lie in each country

The current workflow we have gone ahead with is, by fetching the list of follower’s of a user’s profile, checking any random post on their profile and fetching the geolocation of that follower. This however has lead to inaccurate information.

Can you suggest if there is an alternate to getting this done?

Thank You

Comment: I think checking a random post is pretty inaccurate, though it might be inefficient, I'd prefer to get the geolocation of all posts, and get the country that is the majority in that list. Still though this would be an approximation. You can create a composite country information and use that for each user for example, get top 3 countries that are above some percentage of the posts, and make the user demographic information not a singular country, but a composite of those.

Answer (score 0):

There is no accurate way to get location of a user. You can use 2 methods to get best guess:

1. check the bio information for location
2. get all photos and get geo location area from where most of the posts are coming from.